# MSVC2017 static runtime heap

Tags: visual-c++

I have A.dll and B.dll that links MSVC2017 runtime statically. Do they have separate heaps or share the same heap when they are loaded to the same exe module?

Can I pass std::string with the default allocator, for example, from A.dll to B.dll by value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each has their own separate heap manager. I expect passing `std::string` by value to end badly.

In general, since C++ doesn't define ABI, it's unwise to use C++ classes in general, and standard library classes in particular, in a DLL's public interface. One exception is when a) all modules (EXE and DLLs) link to the DLL runtime, and b) they are all built together, using the same version of the same compiler (at which point, there's little benefit in splitting into multiple modules in the first place).

There are two common approaches to designing DLL interface:

- C-style free functions using only fundamental types, and structs and arrays thereof. Windows API is mostly like that.
- Pointers to abstract classes with no data members and all methods pure virtual - also known as interfaces. At this point, you are using COM, or something substantially COM-like.

In either case, the program must arrange that all resources allocated by a DLL are deallocated in the same DLL. E.g. the DLL may require the caller to pass in buffers for the DLL to fill, so it doesn't return allocated memory; or provide a function the caller must use to deallocate memory allocated by the DLL; or use OS facilities such as `CoTaskMemAlloc` et al, and document this use.

Comment: Why MS cannot make static libs share the same heap?